# I would like to mask source code of react project with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I checked my application that is using webpack on chrome.
I noticed it can be seen the source code by opening “inspection->Source ”
How can I shelter the codes?

Package.json is as following.

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.1",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2",
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Building a react application has an automatic minification process, and there might be extra obfuscation on your code that you can install packages for, but the code that you get after building your is fundamentally always going to be accessible to someone accessing your site via a browser. That's just how the internet works

Comment: Here's a guide on how to use an obfuscation tool with create-react-app: https://blog.jscrambler.com/protecting-your-react-js-source-code-with-jscrambler/